# Elasticsearch matched results on top and remaining after them

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am using `elasticsearch` in my application and I am new to Elasticsearch.

I have an index called `files` with some `tags` associated to it. I want to query them using `tags`. something like this may be

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "tags": [
        "xxx",
        "yyy"
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "created_at": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The above query results only matched ones. But I need all the results with matched results on top. And also `sort` by `created_at`. How to do it?

I TRIED THIS:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "name": [
              "cool",
              "co"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 0
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "created_at": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But results zero always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bool queries with `should`.

Since you want all the docs, you can use a `match_all`. `should` only affects the scoring and not whether documents are included or not.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
    "must" :
     {
               "match_all": { }
            }
    },
    "should": [
 {  "terms" : {
      "tags": [
        "xxx",
        "yyy"
      ]
    } }]
  },
    "sort": [
        { "_score": 
           { "order": "desc" 
         }
        },
        { "created_at":  
         { "order": "desc" 
        } 
       }       
    ]
}
```

Also, sort can take an array so you can pass in your multiple parameters basis which the results should be sorted.

Comment: When I try it from Kibana. should is taking array unlike you mentioned in your answer. should is asking another query term inside.

Comment: I have fixed the syntax, check now.

Comment: tags also needs to be changed I think.

Comment: I tried resulting zero.. updated question please check.

Comment: Can you try with match_all? I changed the answer.